# Triangle on 3d sphere

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a correct triangle on the surface of a sphere. But I don't know how to draw the curved lines correctly. Besides I did not want to start calculating with sine and cosine. One point of the triangle must be located on the north pole.

Could anybody help me! It is highly appreciated!

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) node[anchor=north west]{$z$};


  \shade[ball color = gray!40, opacity = 0.4] (0,0) circle (2cm);
  \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
  \draw (-2,0) arc (180:360:2 and 0.6);
  \draw[dashed] (2,0) arc (0:180:2 and 0.6);
  \fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe make yourself familiar with https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228.

Answer (score 6):

Modified from the good answer of the friendly creature named marmot https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471670/191410

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{-30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Radius}{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{3.6}
\draw[tdplot_screen_coords] (0,0) circle (\Radius);
\begin{scope}
\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=-20:20] (xyz spherical cs:radius=\Radius,latitude=20,longitude=\x)
-- plot[variable=\x,domain=20:90] (xyz spherical cs:radius=\Radius,latitude=\x,longitude=20)
-- plot[variable=\x,domain=90:20] (xyz spherical cs:radius=\Radius,latitude=\x,longitude=-20);
\end{scope}
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,5);
\draw[tdplot_screen_coords,dashed] (0,0) ellipse (4 and 0.5);

\node[anchor=north east] at (xyz spherical cs:radius=\Radius,latitude=20,longitude=-20) {A};
\node[anchor=north west] at (xyz spherical cs:radius=\Radius,latitude=20,longitude=20) {B};
\node[anchor=south east] at (xyz spherical cs:radius=\Radius,latitude=90,longitude=-20) {N};
\node[anchor=west] at (xyz spherical cs:radius=0,latitude=0,longitude=0) {0};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{110}{-30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Radius}{4}
 \draw[tdplot_screen_coords] (0,0) circle (\Radius);
 \begin{scope}
  \draw plot[variable=\x,domain=-20:20] (xyz spherical cs:radius=\Radius,latitude=20,longitude=\x)
  -- plot[variable=\x,domain=20:90] (xyz spherical cs:radius=\Radius,latitude=\x,longitude=20)
  -- plot[variable=\x,domain=90:20] (xyz spherical cs:radius=\Radius,latitude=\x,longitude=-20);
 \end{scope}
 \draw[thick,dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\Radius);
 \draw[thick,->] (0,0,\Radius) -- (0,0,5);
 \draw[dashed] plot[variable=\x,domain=90-\tdplotmainphi:270-\tdplotmainphi] 
 (xyz spherical cs:radius=\Radius,latitude=0,longitude=\x);
 \draw plot[variable=\x,domain=90-\tdplotmainphi:-90-\tdplotmainphi] 
 (xyz spherical cs:radius=\Radius,latitude=0,longitude=\x);
 \node[anchor=north east] at (xyz spherical cs:radius=\Radius,latitude=20,longitude=-20) {A};
 \node[anchor=north west] at (xyz spherical cs:radius=\Radius,latitude=20,longitude=20) {B};
 \node[anchor=south east] at (xyz spherical cs:radius=\Radius,latitude=90,longitude=-20) {N};
 \node[anchor=west] at (xyz spherical cs:radius=0,latitude=0,longitude=0) {0};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @KJO I give a link where there code is originally from. Is this not enough of mentioning?

Comment: @JJMDriessen Thanks

Comment: @KJO I included the name, is this better?

Comment: Thanks. From a geometrical point of view shouldn't the straight line of the triangle also be curved since we are on a sphere?

Comment: @mscm The curvature of the triangles bottom line depends on the view point. For example `\tdplotsetmaincoords{100}{-30}` will give a slightly curved line

Comment: @gigi I see, you are right. I tried this little change, but then the north pole is not fixed anymore.

Comment: @mscm The north pole is no longer fixed, because you look from another direction onto the globe

Comment: Please feel free to revert my edit.

Comment: @marmot Thank you friendly creature!

Comment: Thank you for your help!