# \pgfmathparse/\pgfmathsetmacro produces a strange Incomplete \iffalse;

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I'm trying to calculate things inside the `\newcommand`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\def\spradius{1}
\newcommand*{\projectToSphere}[2]{%
        % calculate a reverse projection point of (#1, #2, 0) on the sphere centered at (0,0,\spradius) of \spradius (radius)
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\XYTwo}{(#1)^2 + (#2)^2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zvalue}{(2 * \XYTwo) / (\XYTwo / \spradius + 4 * \spradius)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xvalue}{(2 * \spradius - \zvalue) / (2 * \spradius) * #1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\yvalue}{(2 * \spradius - \zvalue) / (2 * \spradius) * #2}
        {\xvalue}, {\yvalue}, {\zvalue}
}%

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw[fill=green] (\projectToSphere{3}{4}) circle (0.5pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and I keep getting `! Incomplete \iffalse;`

What I have tried:

- moved `\newcommand` outside of  `tikzpicture`
- moved `\newcommand` outside the document
- added `*` to the `\newcommand`
- direct calculations work, but my actual calculations are more complex, so it will be difficult to have direct calculations inside.

> Is it possible to make `\pgfmathsetmacro` or `\pgfmathparse` to work
>   inside the `\newcommand`?

**Edit: What am  I trying to achieve**
[image: What i ultimately want to draw]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\pgfmathparse` and `\pgfmathsetmacro` work in `\newcommand`, it is just that `tikz` parses the coordinates in a way that is nice in most situations but not here. You can define a function but unfortunately you'd need to insert it component by component.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\def\spradius{1} %<- maybe not a good practice

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{projectToSphereX}{2}{%
\begingroup%
\pgfmathparse{{projectToSphere(#1,#2)}[0]}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{projectToSphereY}{2}{%
\begingroup%
\pgfmathparse{{projectToSphere(#1,#2)}[1]}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{projectToSphereZ}{2}{%
\begingroup%
\pgfmathparse{{projectToSphere(#1,#2)}[2]}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%


\pgfmathdeclarefunction{projectToSphere}{2}{%
\begingroup%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\XYTwo}{(#1)^2 + (#2)^2}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\zvalue}{(2 * \XYTwo) / (\XYTwo / \spradius + 4 * \spradius)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xvalue}{(2 * \spradius - \zvalue) / (2 * \spradius) * #1}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yvalue}{(2 * \spradius - \zvalue) / (2 * \spradius) * #2}%
\edef\pgfmathresult{\xvalue,\yvalue,\zvalue}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%


\begin{document}
    \pgfmathparse{projectToSphere(3,4)}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=green] 
        ({projectToSphereX(3,4)},{projectToSphereY(3,4)},{projectToSphereZ(3,4)}) 
        circle[radius=0.5pt];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It appears to me that you may be looking for nonlinear transformations.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations} 
\newcommand{\PgfmathsetmacroFPU}[2]{\begingroup% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503835
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{#1}{#2}%
\pgfmathsmuggle#1\endgroup}%
\makeatletter
\def\fancyspheretransformation{% similar to the pgfmanual section 103.4.2
\PgfmathsetmacroFPU{\XYTwo}{\pgf@x*\pgf@x+\pgf@y*\pgf@y}%
\PgfmathsetmacroFPU{\zvalue}{-(2*\XYTwo)/(\XYTwo/\spradius+4*\spradius)}%
\PgfmathsetmacroFPU{\xvalue}{(2*\spradius-\zvalue)/(2*\spradius)*\pgf@x}%
\PgfmathsetmacroFPU{\yvalue}{(2*\spradius-\zvalue)/(2*\spradius)*\pgf@y}%
\PgfmathsetmacroFPU{\myx}{cos(\tdplotmainphi)*\xvalue+sin(\tdplotmainphi)*\yvalue}%
\PgfmathsetmacroFPU{\myy}{-cos(\tdplotmaintheta)*sin(\tdplotmainphi)*\xvalue+cos(\tdplotmaintheta)*cos(\tdplotmainphi)*\yvalue-sin(\tdplotmaintheta)*\zvalue}%
\pgf@y=\myy pt% \typeout{z=\zvalue,x=\xvalue,y=\yvalue}%
\pgf@x=\myx pt%
} 
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \def\spradius{4cm} %<- maybe not a good practice
 \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,canvas is xy plane at z=-2]
  \foreach \Color [count=\X starting from -3] in {blue,cyan,green,yellow,orange,red}
   {\foreach \Y in {-3,...,2}
   {\draw[fill=\Color] (\X,\Y) rectangle (\X+1,\Y+1);}}
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[transform shape nonlinear=true,]
  \pgftransformnonlinear{\fancyspheretransformation}
  \foreach \Color [count=\X starting from -3] in {blue,cyan,green,yellow,orange,red}
   {\foreach \Y in {-3,...,2}
   {\draw[fill=\Color] (\X,\Y) rectangle (\X+1,\Y+1);}}
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are two problems with the solution. It does work with raw numbers, but passing other \pgfmathsettedmacro-s does not. And it is unfortunately roughly as fast as fpeval solution of @egreg (from yesterday)

Comment: @dEmigOd I do not understand what you mean by "but passing other `\pgfmathsettedmacro`s does not". Also, you may want to explain what you really want to do.

Comment: I want to back-project an object (colored square) to the sphere. As I didn't find a ready package, I'm calculating position of many small squares and color them appropriately. (I will add the image of what I already have to the post)

Comment: @dEmigOd Like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199715)? Or an arbitrary object like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goLVO.gif)? Then see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471670).

Comment: Added an image, it is not an easy task :-(

Comment: And yes, I saw the first post - I'm also working on animating mobius transformations

Comment: @dEmigOd Why can't you use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199715 for that?

Comment: @dEmigOd I added something using nonlinear transformations to map a grid on the sphere using your map.