# Tikz 3D - Onion layers

Tags: tikz-3d

Am not acquainted yet with 3D diagrams in TikZ and I would like to draw something like the picture attached. Does anybody have any helpful hints?

[image: Onion layers structure of a star]

Comment: Hello. Did you try anything yet? Even in 2D, which is pretty doable with TikZ?

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139472/ ?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471670

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, I'll give it a try in 2D, just to let you start.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \pagecolor{black}
    
    \definecolor{col1}{RGB}{255,255,153}
    \definecolor{col2}{RGB}{153,51,0}
    \definecolor{col3}{RGB}{209,209,224}
    \definecolor{col4}{RGB}{0,230,115}
    \definecolor{col5}{RGB}{204,0,204}
    \definecolor{col6}{RGB}{255,204,204}
    \definecolor{col7}{RGB}{0,153,254}
    \definecolor{col8}{RGB}{255,80,80}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (C) at (0,0);
        
        \fill[outer color=black,inner color=col1] (C) circle (7 cm);
        \fill[ball color=col1,shading=ball] (C) circle (5 cm);
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \foreach \r [count=\i from 1] in {5,4.8,4.6,3,2.5,2.2,1.8,1.6}
                {
                \fill[outer color=col\i,inner color=col\i!70!black] (C) circle (\r cm);
                }
        \end{scope}
        
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,-5) rectangle (-5,5);
            \foreach \r [count=\i from 1] in {5,4.8,4.6,3,2.5,2.2,1.8,1.6}
                {
                \filldraw[col\i!70!black] (C) ellipse (0.3*\r cm and \r cm);
                }
        \end{scope}
        
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (90:1.6) arc (90:270:0.3*1.6 cm and 1.6 cm) arc (-90:90:1.6);
            \filldraw[ball color=col8,shading=ball] (C) circle (1.6 cm);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: look into this star]

**EDIT:** I edited my script to eliminate redundancies and inappropriate class declaration, and above all, to let you define once and for all the slices radii. I tried to add some shading into each slice but it's not working yet (apart from writing each slice in an individual code line, which I find disappointing). I'll let you know later if I find a way to do that correctly.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \pagecolor{black}
    
    \definecolor{col1}{RGB}{255,255,153}
    \definecolor{col2}{RGB}{153,51,0}
    \definecolor{col3}{RGB}{209,209,224}
    \definecolor{col4}{RGB}{0,230,115}
    \definecolor{col5}{RGB}{204,0,204}
    \definecolor{col6}{RGB}{255,204,204}
    \definecolor{col7}{RGB}{0,153,254}
    \definecolor{col8}{RGB}{255,102,0}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (C) at (0,0);
        
        \def\a{5}   \def\b{4.8}  \def\c{4.6} \def\d{3}
        \def\e{2.2} \def\f{1.8}  \def\g{1}   \def\h{0.8}
        
        \fill[outer color=black,inner color=col1] (C) circle (6.5 cm);
        \fill[ball color=col1,shading=ball] (C) circle (5 cm);

        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \foreach \r [count=\i] in {\a,\b,\c,\d,\e,\f,\g,\h}
                {
                \fill[outer color=col\i,inner color=col\i!70!black] (C) circle (\r cm);
                }
        \end{scope}
        
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,-5) rectangle (-5,5);
            \foreach \r [count=\i] in {\a,\b,\c,\d,\e,\f,\g,\h}
                {
                \fill[col\i!70!black] (C) ellipse (0.3*\r cm and \r cm);
                }
        \end{scope}
        
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (90:\h) arc (90:270:0.3*\h cm and \h cm) arc (-90:90:\h);
            \fill[ball color=col8,shading=ball] (C) circle (\h cm);
        \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It could be more parametrized, especially for the most inner radius, but you'll get the point.

Comment: Its a very cool image!

Comment: It is really great!!!! Thanx a lot

Comment: Very very nice....+1.

Comment: I edited my post and added a new picture.

Comment: Beautiful! Splendid, literally!