# How to do logarithmic shading with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

Using TikZ, the `shade` option is very convenient to produce color shadings, but it produces only linear color gradients. Is it possible to obtain other transitions, and especially a logarithmic one?

Thanks!

## Edit:

Here is an example for the linear case:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[left color=black, right color=white] (0,0) rectangle (10,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: linear shading]

Comment: You can with `\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading`. Check the manual or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54193/how-to-draw-a-shaded-sphere for examples.

Comment: Thank you @percusse, I am pretty sure this is what I need, but the code I have to put into the function is puzzling to me! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you include a MWE and the details about the shading direction etc. ? Then we can look at it together.

Comment: I have added a MWE. I would like something very simple : a horizontal band changing from black to white with a logarithmic progression. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are some examples.

- R=G=B=x (your MWE)
- R=G=B=x
- R=G=B=x²
- R=G=B=√x
- R=G=B=log(1+x)
- R=G=B=log(1+9x)
- R=G=B= ... [well ...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill(-11,0)|-(0,-2)|-(11,2)|-cycle;
    \shade[left color=black,right color=white](-10,-1)rectangle(10,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading{LBRW}{\pgfpoint{0bp}{0bp}}{\pgfpoint{100bp}{100bp}}{}{
    pop 50 div .5 sub % u
    dup dup % u u u
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill(-11,0)|-(0,-2)|-(11,2)|-cycle;
    \shade[shading=LBRW](-10,-1)rectangle(10,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading{dup mul LBRW}{\pgfpoint{0bp}{0bp}}{\pgfpoint{100bp}{100bp}}{}{
    pop 50 div .5 sub % u
    dup mul % u²
    dup dup % u² u² u²
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill(-11,0)|-(0,-2)|-(11,2)|-cycle;
    \shade[shading=dup mul LBRW](-10,-1)rectangle(10,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading{sqrt LBRW}{\pgfpoint{0bp}{0bp}}{\pgfpoint{100bp}{100bp}}{}{
    pop 50 div .5 sub % u
    sqrt % √u
    dup dup % √u √u √u
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill(-11,0)|-(0,-2)|-(11,2)|-cycle;
    \shade[shading=sqrt LBRW](-10,-1)rectangle(10,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading{1 add log LBRW}{\pgfpoint{0bp}{0bp}}{\pgfpoint{100bp}{100bp}}{}{
    pop 50 div .5 sub % u
    1 add log % ㏒(1+u)
    dup dup % ㏒(1+u) ㏒(1+u) ㏒(1+u)
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill(-11,0)|-(0,-2)|-(11,2)|-cycle;
    \shade[shading=1 add log LBRW](-10,-1)rectangle(10,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading{9 mul 1 add log LBRW}{\pgfpoint{0bp}{0bp}}{\pgfpoint{100bp}{100bp}}{}{
    pop 50 div .5 sub % u
    9 mul 1 add log % ㏒(1+9u)
    dup dup % ㏒(1+9u) ㏒(1+9u) ㏒(1+9u)
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill(-11,0)|-(0,-2)|-(11,2)|-cycle;
    \shade[shading=9 mul 1 add log LBRW](-10,-1)rectangle(10,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading{logistic}{\pgfpoint{0bp}{0bp}}{\pgfpoint{100bp}{100bp}}{}{
    50 div .5 sub exch % v U
    50 div .5 sub 4 mul exch % 4u v
    dup 1 exch sub % 4u v 1-v
    2 index % 4u v (1-v) 4u
    mul mul % u 4uv(1-v)
    dup 1 exch sub 2 index mul mul
    dup 1 exch sub 2 index mul mul
    dup 1 exch sub 2 index mul mul
    dup 1 exch sub 2 index mul mul
    dup 1 exch sub 2 index mul mul
    exch pop dup dup
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill(-11,0)|-(0,-2)|-(11,2)|-cycle;
    \shade[shading=logistic](-10,-1)rectangle(10,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### Remarks

- `dup` duplicates the topmost element.
- The `dup dup` at every very end is actually unnecessary.
- If you leave only a single number in the stack, PDF-renderer will treat it as the grayscale.
- If there are three, they are R, G, B respectively.
- If there are 0 or 2 or 4, 5, 6, ... I do not know.
- `pop` discards the topmost element.
- The `pop` at every very beginning throws away the y-coordinate, which is useless except the last case.
- Replacing `pop` by `swap`, you can leave the y-coordinate at the bottom alone. But then `dup dup` becomes necessary.
- For more information, see Ti*k*Z manual **IX.110.2.3 General (Functional) Shadings**.
- For ever more information, see PDF manual **8.7.4.5.2 Type 1 (Function-Based) Shadings**.
- See also **Annex B (normative) Operators in Type 4 Functions**.

Comment: Thank you! Could you just explain what `pop` mean, and why `dup` commands are needed?

Comment: @Tobard I updated.

Comment: @Symbol1, I notice you say that `dup dup` at the end is unnecessary, but I'm not sure about this. When the shading is created, the colour model needs to be specified (and by default `pgf` uses RGB). The `dup dup` is missing in your `logistic` shading and the resulting PDF gives an error in Adobe Reader for me.

Comment: @DavidPurton If Adobe reader complains, then it is right/I am wrong. Don't skip `dup dup`.