# Shading of sphere

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

The second answer in

[How to draw a shaded sphere?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54193/how-to-draw-a-shaded-sphere)

is a yellow shaded sphere. How can I turn it to be black and white? Thanks for any help! I have been trying for an hour, changing values randomly but did't achieve anything, since I don't understand the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colors are set here:

```
%% currently there is just one number in the stack.
%% we need three corresponding to the RGB values
dup
0.4
```

You have to put the RGB values you desire to change the color, for example if you set:

```
dup 
0.4 
0.5
```

You get something like pink.

RGB means red, green and blue, the primary colors, in this notation they have value from 0 (= no light) to 1 (= full light), for example:

```
r g b 
0 0 0 = black
1 0 0 = red
0 1 0 = green
0 0 1 = blue
1 1 1 = white
```

If all the 3 values are equal to a value from 0 to 1, you get the scale of gray.

As you said in a comment, if you put all the rgb equal you lost the shade, I think you can reach you desired result by changing other commands, but don't know them, because they are a simplified form of a subset of the PostScript language, search for `\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading` in the Ti_k_Z & PGF Manual and see Section 3.9.4  [here]
(http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) for more info.

Instead, I suggest to you to use a simpler solution, if you don't like CroCo's one, try something like this (modify the values until you find what you're looking for):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclareradialshading{sphere}{\pgfpoint{0.5cm}{0.5cm}}%
   {rgb(0cm)=(1,1,1);
    rgb(0.9cm)=(0.7,0.7,0.7);
    rgb(1cm)=(0.5,0.5,0.5);
    rgb(1.05cm)=(0,0,0)}

\begin{document}
    \pgfuseshading{sphere}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried changing the values, but I cannot get it to be black and white. Is there some way to simply remove the colour while preserving the shading?

Comment: @lamkingming They are RGB values. So if you keep them the same you get tones of gray

Comment: @percusse But when I set all three of them to be the same, the shading somehow goes away

Comment: check the last comment of Simon about the color with matte and RGB @lamkingming

Comment: @percusse Yeah I did saw that, but I still can't do it after trying for an hour, that's why I post the this question. I have no knowlege of doing similar things, like I don't even know what "dup abs add div mul" means. Thanks anyway

Comment: @lamkingming You can find the meaning of `dup abs add div mul` are taken from PostScript language, see Section 3.9.4 here: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf. Meanwhile, I'm trying to get a gray shading as you need with a simplest code...

Comment: @lamkingming Change the last `0.4` to `dup` and decrease separately the numbers `0.6` or `0.4` until you are happy in Simon's answer. It makes it gray.

Comment: @percusse Great! You should post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're seeking?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border={10pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}  

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[ 
  sphereBlack/.style={ball color = black},
  sphereYellow/.style={ball color = yellow}
]

\shade[sphereBlack]  (0,0) circle (1cm); 
\shade[sphereYellow] (3,0) circle (1cm); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I need a sphere whose light area consist of a larger proportion of the sphere, yet at the same time the darkest area are quit dark. For example it wouldn't work if I change your black sphere to a gray, since the dardest area will be gray and so not dark enough. See the post I refer to in the question, there is two example "That's not a sphere" and "That's a sphere". I want somthing like "That's a sphere".

Comment: @lamkingming, under  Choosing a Shading Type section in the manual, there are several options for this matter. Take a look at `inner color` and `outer color`