# Blochsphere Package Shading

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-3dplot, physics

I am using the [blochsphere package](https://ctan.org/pkg/blochsphere?lang=de) and have a problem with shading of the drawn ball. Using the color white for the ball and opacity=0.7 makes it quite dark greyish. I dont want to turn down the opacity, since this would make the 3D effect of the shade vanish even more. But since I am already using white as a color I dont know how to make the ball look more white.

Can anyone help me out?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,calc,math,angles,quotes}
\usepackage{blochsphere}
\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}
%%%% Change these parameters to change the position of psi, or the size/rotation of the sphere
\def\rotationSphere{-10}
\def\tiltSphere{10} %0.01
\def\radiusSphere{2cm}
\def\psiLat{90}
\def\psiLon{45}

\begin{blochsphere}[radius=\radiusSphere,opacity=0.7,rotation=\rotationSphere,tilt=\tiltSphere,color=white]
  %\drawBallGrid[style={opacity=.3}]{30}{30}
  
  % Draw the vertical plane
  %\drawLongitudeCircle[]{\rotationSphere} % draw the longitude that face us to delimit the sphere
  %Farbeinstellung
  %draw={rgb,255:red,199; green,199; blue,199}
  \drawLongitudeCircle[style={opacity=0.3,line width=0.8}]{90-0}
  % ... and the equatorial plane
  \drawLatitudeCircle[style={opacity=0.3,line width=0.8}]{90-90} %style={dashed}
\end{blochsphere}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @manual about `3dtools`, you visit this https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools and download `tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex`, save with name `tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex` in the same folder where you put the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not understand all your requests.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=110,theta=70},line cap=butt,
        line join=round,declare function={R=2.5;},c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]
        \path
        (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
        (0,0,R)  coordinate (N)
        (0,0,-R)  coordinate (S)
        ({R*cos(60)}, {R*sin(60)},0)  coordinate (A);
\node (a) at (A) [below]{$\Psi$};       
        \draw[3d/screen coords,fill=gray,opacity=0.3] (O) circle[radius=R]; 
        \path pic{3d/circle on sphere={R=R,C={(O)}}};
        \path  pic{3d/circle on sphere={R=R,C={(O)},P={(O)}, n={(0,1,0)}}}; 

\draw[3d/hidden] (S) -- (N)  (O)--(R,0,0) (O)--(0,R,0) 
;
\draw[ultra thick, orange, - latex,dashed] (O) -- (A);
\draw[3d/visible, -latex] (R,0,0) -- (R + 4,0,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[3d/visible, -latex] (0,R,0) -- (0,R + 1,0) node[right]{$y$};
\draw[3d/visible, -latex] (0,0,R) -- (0,0,R + 1) node[above]{$z$};
        \path foreach \p/\g in {O/150,S/0,N/-30}
        {(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can use
`\shade[ball color=white,3d/screen coords,opacity=0.7] (O) circle[radius=R];`

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=110,theta=70},line cap=butt,
        line join=round,declare function={R=2.5;},c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]
        \path
        (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
        (0,0,R)  coordinate (N)
        (0,0,-R)  coordinate (S)
        ({R*cos(60)}, {R*sin(60)},0)  coordinate (A);
\node (a) at (A) [below]{$\Psi$};       
    \shade[ball color=white,3d/screen coords,opacity=0.7] (O) circle[radius=R];
        \path pic{3d/circle on sphere={R=R,C={(O)}}};
        \path  pic{3d/circle on sphere={R=R,C={(O)},P={(O)}, n={(0,1,0)}}};

\draw[3d/hidden] (S) -- (N)  (O)--(R,0,0) (O)--(0,R,0)
;
\draw[ultra thick, orange, - latex,dashed] (O) -- (A);
\draw[3d/visible, -latex] (R,0,0) -- (R + 4,0,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[3d/visible, -latex] (0,R,0) -- (0,R + 1,0) node[right]{$y$};
\draw[3d/visible, -latex] (0,0,R) -- (0,0,R + 1) node[above]{$z$};
        \path foreach \p/\g in {O/150,S/0,N/-30}
        {(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}};

        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great solution! Is it possible to make the gray filling as in the answer from NguyenVanChi1998 (meaning that there is lighting and shadows?)

Comment: @manuel459 I think yes. You can change the number `0.3` in this line by ` \draw[3d/screen coords,fill=gray,opacity=0.3] (O) circle[radius=R]; `  another number, for example `0.7`.

Comment: @manuel459 You can see here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54193/how-to-draw-a-shaded-sphere

Comment: Thank you! Just what I have been looking for. I unfortunately get the error " I did not find the tikz library '3dtools'". Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Oh, I realize that `3dtools` use the `circle` command to draw a sphere! in other words, `3dtools` draw the silhouette of a sphere

Answer (score 2):

A bit with Asymptote, compile on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/

I also do not understand your desire.

Reference:

https://asy.marris.fr/asymptote/Solides/index.html#fig_ab05_271008_sphere

https://asy.marris.fr/asymptote/Reperes_3D/index.html#fig_cs01_300509_coordonnees_spheriques

```
settings.render=8;
import solids;
size(5cm);

currentprojection=orthographic(1,0.3,0.3);

revolution b=sphere(O,1);
draw(surface(b),white+opacity(.5));

skeleton s;
b.transverse(s,reltime(b.g,0.5),P=currentprojection);

draw(s.transverse.back,dashed);
draw(s.transverse.front);
draw(rotate(90,X)*s.transverse.back,dashed);
draw(rotate(90,X)*s.transverse.front);

real rayon=0.8, phi=90, theta=45;
triple pM=dir(phi,theta);

draw((O--pM),dashed+green+0.7bp,Arrow3(size=7));
label(Label("$\psi$",yellow),pM,0.5dir(-90));

xaxis3("$x$",1,1.5,Arrow3);
xaxis3(-1.3,1,linetype(new real[] {8,8}));
yaxis3("$y$",1,1.5,Arrow3);
yaxis3(-1.3,1,linetype(new real[] {8,8}));
zaxis3("$z$",1,1.5,Arrow3);
zaxis3(0,1,linetype(new real[] {8,8}));
```

[image]