# Blochsphere package - shading (brighter ball)

Tags: draw, physics

I am using the [blochsphere package](https://ctan.org/pkg/blochsphere?lang=de) and have a problem with shading of the drawn ball. Using the color white for the ball and opacity=0.7 makes it quite dark greyish. I dont want to turn down the opacity, since this would make the 3D effect of the shade vanish even more. But since I am already using white as a color I dont know how to make the ball look more white.

Can anyone help me out?
I'd also appreciate any hints on which tags I could use here - tikz and physics seems quite inappropriate.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,calc,math,angles,quotes}
\usepackage{blochsphere}
\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}
%%%% Change these parameters to change the position of psi, or the size/rotation of the sphere
\def\rotationSphere{-10}
\def\tiltSphere{10} %0.01
\def\radiusSphere{2cm}
\def\psiLat{90}
\def\psiLon{45}

\begin{blochsphere}[radius=\radiusSphere,opacity=0.7,rotation=\rotationSphere,tilt=\tiltSphere,color=white]
  %\drawBallGrid[style={opacity=.3}]{30}{30}
  
  % Draw the vertical plane
  %\drawLongitudeCircle[]{\rotationSphere} % draw the longitude that face us to delimit the sphere
  %Farbeinstellung
  %draw={rgb,255:red,199; green,199; blue,199}
  \drawLongitudeCircle[style={opacity=0.3,line width=0.8}]{90-0}
  % ... and the equatorial plane
  \drawLatitudeCircle[style={opacity=0.3,line width=0.8}]{90-90} %style={dashed}
\end{blochsphere}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that it was asked there a day ago, but I only got an answer here, where there are more people having the same issues regarding the bloch sphere.

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618117?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blochsphere Package Shading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618117/blochsphere-package-shading)