# How to use 3dtools?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzlibrary

I tried using [3dtools](http://I%20did%20not%20find%20the%20tikz%20library%20%273dtools%27) but it gives me the error `I did not find the tikz library '3dtools'`. How can I solve this? Usually packages are loaded by Texmaker automatically.

Comment: The link to provide reads: "http://i%20did%20not%20find%20the%20tikz%20library%20%273dtools%27/" - is this on purpose?

Comment: Most likely copy-and-pasting to the wrong blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dowload `3dtools` at [here](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools). Download [this file](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools/blob/master/tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex), save this file with name `tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex` and put the same folder where you put the file that you want to compile.

Comment: I get the error "Missing \begin{document}" and missing "$" within that file. What is wrong there?

Comment: What if file do you compile?

Comment: I compile the file I am working in. It only contains the code you provided in the question regarding the blochsphere. It is in the same folder as the tikzlibrary3dtools.code

Comment: Can you compile file at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618117/blochsphere-package-shading/618440#618440 ?

Comment: No - i get the error mentioned.

Comment: I posted full code. How about system of Text (Miktex or textlive). Do you copy all my code?

Comment: I tried to copy all your code, since it didn't work. I use Miktex.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130412/discussion-between-manuel459-and-minhthien-2016).