# How to create a ball shading and to customize 3D lighting manually?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, shading

TikZ `shading=ball` creates a perfect 3D ball perspective, but it has no option to change the lighting angle, the contrast, radius of light, etc (or I am not aware of). I tried to create a 3D ball by `radial` shading. However, I still do not know how to change the place of `inner color`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,shading=ball,minimum width=3cm] (ball) at (0,0) {};
\node[circle,outer color=blue!60!black,inner color=white,minimum width=3cm] (radial) at (4,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Which is the standard method to customize the 3D lighting?

Comment: look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54193/how-to-draw-a-shaded-sphere

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should go to section 83.2.2 Radial Shadings of the pgfmanual (version October 25, 2010).

Here is a solution in which the color of that example is a bit changed and different `center points` are used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}

% spheres definitions

\pgfdeclareradialshading{sphere}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}% 
{rgb(0cm)=(1,1,1);
rgb(0.7cm)=(0.7,0.1,0); rgb(1cm)=(0.5,0.05,0); rgb(1.05cm)=(1,1,1)}

\pgfdeclareradialshading{sphere1}{\pgfpoint{0.5cm}{0cm}}% 
{rgb(0cm)=(1,1,1);
rgb(0.7cm)=(0.7,0.1,0); rgb(1cm)=(0.5,0.05,0); rgb(1.05cm)=(1,1,1)}


\pgfdeclareradialshading{sphere2}{\pgfpoint{0.5cm}{0.5cm}}% 
{rgb(0cm)=(1,1,1);
rgb(0.7cm)=(0.7,0.1,0); rgb(1cm)=(0.5,0.05,0); rgb(1.05cm)=(1,1,1)}


\pgfdeclareradialshading{sphere3}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0.5cm}}% 
{rgb(0cm)=(1,1,1);
rgb(0.7cm)=(0.7,0.1,0); rgb(1cm)=(0.5,0.05,0); rgb(1.05cm)=(1,1,1)}

\pgfdeclareradialshading{sphere4}{\pgfpoint{-0.2cm}{0.5cm}}% 
{rgb(0cm)=(1,1,1);
rgb(0.7cm)=(0.7,0.1,0); rgb(1cm)=(0.5,0.05,0); rgb(1.05cm)=(1,1,1)}



\pgfuseshading{sphere}\pgfuseshading{sphere1}\pgfuseshading{sphere2}\pgfuseshading{sphere3}\pgfuseshading{sphere4}

\end{document}
```

This leads to:

[image]

---

To further customize the lighting you should play with:

- the coloring;
- the coloring position.

To be more clear, `rgb(0.7cm)=(0.7,0.1,0);` it's saying that you want the color `(0.7,0.1,0)` at 0.7cm.

Here is a slightly different example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}

% spheres definitions

\pgfdeclareradialshading{sphere}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}% 
{rgb(0cm)=(1,1,1);
rgb(0.7cm)=(0.7,0.1,0); rgb(1cm)=(0.5,0.05,0); rgb(1.05cm)=(1,1,1)}

\pgfdeclareradialshading{sphere1}{\pgfpoint{0.5cm}{0cm}}% 
{rgb(0cm)=(1,1,1);
rgb(0.4cm)=(0.7,0.1,0); rgb(0.6cm)=(0.5,0.05,0); rgb(1.05cm)=(1,1,1)}


\pgfdeclareradialshading{sphere2}{\pgfpoint{0.5cm}{0.5cm}}% 
{rgb(0cm)=(1,1,1);
rgb(0.9cm)=(0.7,0.1,0); rgb(1cm)=(0.5,0.05,0); rgb(1.05cm)=(1,1,1)}


\pgfdeclareradialshading{sphere3}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0.5cm}}% 
{rgb(0cm)=(1,1,1);
rgb(0.5cm)=(0.7,0.1,0); rgb(0.75cm)=(0.6,0.075,0); rgb(1cm)=(0.5,0.05,0); rgb(1.05cm)=(1,1,1)}

\pgfdeclareradialshading{sphere4}{\pgfpoint{-0.2cm}{0.5cm}}% 
{rgb(0cm)=(1,1,1);
rgb(0.2cm)=(0.7,0.1,0); rgb(0.9cm)=(0.5,0.05,0); rgb(1.05cm)=(1,1,1)}


\pgfuseshading{sphere}\pgfuseshading{sphere1}\pgfuseshading{sphere2}\pgfuseshading{sphere3}\pgfuseshading{sphere4}

\end{document}
```

which gives you:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I found it and in the subsequent section 83.3. My bad! but it still has lesser options than what I expected to have for flexible 3D lighting.

Comment: I'll edit my question to further customize the lighting.

Comment: That's something useful that I was unable to find in the manual.