# Using Beamer bullets in poster

Tags: beamer, itemize, baposter

I am creating a LaTeX poster with the [Baposter template](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/), and would like to use the Beamer 3D bullet as my `itemize` bullet, like the one shown below:

[image]

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58633/how-to-create-a-ball-shading-and-to-customize-3d-lighting-manually shows how to draw a 3D ball using tikz; you should then be able to set this as your 'bullet' in a list

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks @prettygully!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @prettygully's comment and [How to create a ball shading and to customize 3D lighting manually?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58633/how-to-create-a-ball-shading-and-to-customize-3d-lighting-manually), this is what I have achieved:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\colouredcircle}{%
  \tikz{\useasboundingbox (-0.2em,-0.32em) rectangle(0.2em,0.32em);
        \draw[ball color=blue,shading=ball,line width=0.03em] (0,0) circle(0.18em);}}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\colouredcircle}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item 1.
  \item Item 2.
  \item Item 3.
  \item Item 4.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```