# Beamer Bullets in Latex Article

Tags: beamer, itemize, article, circles, bullets

Is it possible to use Beamer bullets in latex article ? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXoCL.png or 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1lPJ.png

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

   \begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item-1
        \item Item-2

        \item[--] Item-3
        \item[--] Item-4

        \item[*] Item-5
        \item[*] Item-6

    \end{itemize}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: As follows from @samcarter answer, it is possible, but where you like to publish your article? Do publisher will allowed to have such unusual fancy bullets in article? And what you like to tell with them to reader? Don't do this! (well, my comment is very opinion based ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can borrow the definitions of the bullets from http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty

Lets take the bullet as an example. The beamer definition is

```
\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{circle}{\small\raise0.5pt\hbox{\textbullet}}
```

To use this in an article:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\renewcommand\labelitemi{\small\raise0.5pt\hbox{\textbullet}}
%\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\raise0.25ex\hbox{\vrule width 1ex height 1ex}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item-1
        \item Item-2
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

In principle the same can be done with the more complex shaped like the 3D ball, but as this is already solved in [Using Beamer bullets in poster](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184080/using-beamer-bullets-in-poster) it's easier to borrow the code there

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\colouredcircle}{%
\tikz{\useasboundingbox (-0.2em,-0.32em) rectangle(0.2em,0.32em);
    \draw[ball color=blue,shading=ball,line width=0.03em] (0,0) circle(0.18em);}}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\colouredcircle}


\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
       \item Item-1
       \item Item-2
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: as far as I understand question, OP like to have four different style of "boolets" as show in provided links in one `itemize` environment. Unussual request, which is simple handled with standard characters (which are available in used font), however importing  bullets from `beamer` probably you need to define four commands for different "boolets" style and them used in items.

Comment: @Zarko I understood the images to visualize which bullets he wants and see no indicator that he wants to combine them in a single document. But based on previous questions you are probably right.

Comment: I like to discourage OP to doing this already in my answer, however, seems that he persist in his attention :-( Not because this is difficult to achieve (you show that this is quit easy), but the obtained result (to my opinion) will look strange and ugly.

Comment: Thanks a lot @samcarter for your answer. at-Zarko, May be my question was not clear enough. My goal is to change the default bullet points (\bullets , -- or *) and use the beamer theme type of bullets. I am trying to use $\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{ball}{\raise0.2pt\beamer@usesphere{item projected}{bigsphere}}$ but I can't use in the same way you mentioned.

Comment: @ibrahimkbd It does not work because you have to copy the definition of `\beamer@usesphere{item projected}{bigsphere}` etc. too. Otherwise that's just an undefined command.

Comment: Thank you for your help! 
Is there any simpler way to activate square ?

Comment: @ibrahimkbd Easier than a simple rule? I doubt that.

Comment: I see. In that case is it possible to control the size of \item[$\blacksquare$] blacksquare?

Comment: @ibrahimkbd With the rule from beamer, controlling the size is easy :)

Comment: I could control the size of the sphere pretty easily (as you gave the code) but I couldn't create the square :(

Comment: @ibrahimkbd I did that a few seconds ago.