# water inside 3D tube

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

[image: a tube with water molecules inside]

How can I generate the above image using TikZ. The oval inside tube represents water and arrows indicates the dipole orientation of water.
What I was able to get so far is pasted below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>


\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{30}{10}
\tikzset{every circle/.append style={x=1cm, y=1cm}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, rotate=90]

% --- Independent parameters ---
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\tA{3600}      % 10 turns 360 degree x 10=3600
\def\zA{1}                         % A begin point, define the length of cylinder 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\tB{30}      % tB end of turn 
\def\zB{5}                         % B end point
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\NbPt{130}     % number of circles for drawing the helix portion 13 times 10 turns =130
\def\rhelixdots{0.14}              % radius of circles  forming helix

 % --- Draw helix ---
\pgfmathsetmacro\tone{\tA}
\pgfmathsetmacro\tlast{\tB}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ttwo{\tone+(\tlast-\tone)/(\NbPt-1)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\p{360*(\zB-\zA)/(\tB-\tA)}

\foreach \t in {\tone,\ttwo,...,\tlast}{%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\shadingcolor}{40*sin(\t+180)+80}
\shade[ball color=blue!\shadingcolor] ({0.7*cos(\t)},{0.7*sin(\t)},{\p*(\t-\tA)/360+\zA}) circle[radius=\rhelixdots];
\shade[ball color=red!\shadingcolor] ({0.7*cos(\t)},{0.7*sin(\t)},{\p*(\t-\tA)/360+\zA+0.2}) circle[radius=\rhelixdots];
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Looking for help, please have a look as well to this post [Changing the view angle distort 3d tube image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251483/changing-the-view-angle-distort-3d-tube-image)

Comment: You could also plot only a single layer of the tube and use that...?

Comment: actually I'm interested in two layers blue and red

Comment: what is the pattern a double helix?

Comment: yes, it is a double helix in order to have 2 type of atoms blue and red

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is much easier to just draw everything in the correct order instead of using 3d coordinates (or layers).

The crucial part is the last dozen of lines:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\newdimen\r
\newdimen\R
\newcount\n

\tikzmath{
  \n = 19;                            % Molecules per winding
  \R = 100pt;                         % Tube radius
  \e = 0.9;                           % Eccentricity
  \t = 1.15;                          % Tightening factor
  \F = floor(\n/2);                   % Crucial to perform the clever cycles
  \G = \n-\F;                         %   (see the interesting part)
  \r = \R*sin(180/\n)*\t;             % 1/2 side of regular n-polygon, times t
}

% ##################################################### START OF BORING PART #

% These are the basic styles.
\tikzset{
  spirals/.cd,
    0/.style={draw, fill=white!70!black}, % {shade, ball color=white}
    1/.style={draw, fill=white!90!black}, % {shade, ball color=gray}
    8/.style={draw, fill=white!20!black}, % {shade, ball color=black}
    9/.style={opacity=0}
}

% Shaping the border. Boring.
\newcommand\ifisborderthen[4]{
  \ifthenelse{
        \(#2=0 \AND #3=0\)
    \OR \(#1=16 \AND #2<5\)
    \OR \(#1=3 \AND #2<1\)
    \OR \( #1=1  \AND \( #2<7 \OR \(#2<8 \AND #3=0\) \) \)
    \OR \( \(#1=17 \OR #1=2 \) \AND \(#2<5 \OR \(#2<6 \AND #3=0\)\) \)
    \OR \( \(#1=18 \OR #1=19\) \AND \(#2<6 \OR \(#2<7 \AND #3=0\)\) \)
  }{#4}{}}

% Shaping the hole. Boring.
\newcommand\ifisholethen[4]{
  \ifthenelse{
        \( #2<4 \AND \(2>#1 \OR #1>16\) \)
    \OR \(#1=1 \AND #2<5\)
    \OR \(#1=2 \AND #2<1 \AND #3=0\)
    \OR \(#1=19 \AND #2<6\)
    \OR \(#1=18 \AND #2<5\)
    \OR \(#1=17 \AND #2<5 \AND #3=0\)
  }{#4}{}}

% ################################################# START OF INTERESTING PART #

% We define a parametric key to apply the styles in a convenient way
\tikzset{
  molecule/.code args={#1in winding #2of spiral #3}{ % <-- HOCKETY POCKETY
    \tikzset{spirals/#3}                             % Draw everything.
    \ifisborderthen{#1}{#2}{#3}{\tikzset{spirals/8}} % Mark Borders.
    \ifisholethen{#1}{#2}{#3}{\tikzset{spirals/9}}}} % Punch holes.

\foreach \a [evaluate = \a using int(\a)]        % We cross (nearing viewer)
         in { \F, ..., 1                         %   first the lower side and
            , \F+1, \F+2, \F+..., \F+\G }        %   then the upper side
\foreach \z in {0, ..., 9}                       %     of ten windings
\foreach \h in {0, 1}                            %       of two spirals.
\path [molecule = \a in winding \z of spiral \h] % <--- HIGITUS FIGITUS
      ( {sqrt(1-\e^2)*\R*cos(-\a*360/\n)}        % This is the parametrization
      , {             \R*sin(-\a*360/\n)} )      %   of an ellipse.
        ++ ({\a*2*2*\r/\n}, 0)                   % We cut them open and
        ++ ({\z*2*2*\r}   , 0)                   % join them. Hence, spirals
        ++ ({\h*2*\r}     , 0)                   % that we intertwine.
        ++ (rand*360:rand*\r/20)                 % Some wobblyness.
      circle (\r);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image: Nice version]

I didn't draw the thingies inside because I don't understand them.
I didn't use faux-3d balls because I think they're horrible.

The depth *fog* effect (or the balls) are easy to add, and you already know how to do it. I focused on reproducing the given picture.

---

***UPDATE!!*** It's 3D!

[image: Horrible version]

The new style is in the comments inside `spirals`.

---

***UPDATE 2!!*** It's 3D-er!

Interestingly enough, the shading only eats the first coordinate.
As an example, compare the previous figure (in which shading was computed using only the coordinate along the ellipse) with the following one that uses the full coordinate of the circles, except for the wobbliness correction:

```
\path [molecule = \a in winding \z of spiral \h] % <--- HIGITUS FIGITUS
      ( {sqrt(1-\e^2)*\R*cos(-\a*360/\n)         % Ellipses parametrized.
           + \a*2*2*\r/\n                        % We cut them open and
           + \z*2*2*\r                           % join them. Hence, spirals
           + \h*2*\r                    }        % that we intertwine.
      , {             \R*sin(-\a*360/\n)} )
        ++ (rand*360:rand*\r/20)                 % Some wobblyness.
      circle (\r);
```

[image: Horriblest version]

I didn't realize at first, but this allows for some tricks.
As an example, consider this simple permutation:

```
\path [molecule = \a in winding \z of spiral \h]
           ({\a*2*2*\r/\n}, 0)
        ++ ({\z*2*2*\r}   , 0)
        ++ ({\h*2*\r}     , 0)
        ++ (rand*360:rand*\r/20)
        ++( {sqrt(1-\e^2)*\R*cos(-\a*360/\n)}
          , {             \R*sin(-\a*360/\n)} )
      circle (\r);
```

[image: Cool version]

That looks like a point light source inside the tube. Neat!

Comment: I would like  to stress that the balls are not centered, maybe some rotations of the balls in order to have the same look for all balls like first balls from beginning? Maybe the posts [How to create a ball shading and to customize 3D lighting manually?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58633/how-to-create-a-ball-shading-and-to-customize-3d-lighting-manually) and [How to draw a shaded sphere?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54193/how-to-draw-a-shaded-sphere)  can provide some suggestions?

Comment: @Andrei And I would like to stress that you are being erratic with your requests. You asked for a picture to be reproduced, and I reproduced the non trivial part of the picture. You did *not* ask for shading and effects. Nonetheless, answer updated.