# Changing the view angle distort 3D tube image

Tags: 3d

In previous post [water inside 3d tube](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251476/water-inside-3d-tube) I added a code.

What I need is to have a look from front, but the problem is, if I change the angle from `\tdplotsetmaincoords{30}{10}`
to `\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{10}` I get a wrong picture with wrong overlap order of atoms like in image below
[image: wrong view]
How is possible to get a nice look from the front view, e.g. like in the image below?
[image: corect picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is given by [Paolo Brasolin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/82186/paolo-brasolin)'s code,  see [water inside 3D tube](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251476/water-inside-3d-tube)
[image]
[image]