# changing highlighting in shading in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

In TikZ, how do you change the position of the "highlight" in the shading of a circle, such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \tikz \shade[ball color=red] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{document}
```

so that the highlight appears in the exact middle of the circle? The default position of the highlight seems to be a bit to the northwest.

Comment: Can you please show us a compilable code, not only a code snippet?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I added a short LaTeX file so that the code is compilable.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58633/how-to-create-a-ball-shading-and-to-customize-3d-lighting-manually

Comment: @MichaelPalmer That reference has everything I need (and more!) for customizing the shading of circles. Many thanks.