# Is it possible to define the position of top bottom and middle color in fill?

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

In the following example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc,shapes,shapes.geometric,patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[bottom color=cyan!60!black, top color=red, middle color = blue!20!white] (0,0) rectangle (4,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to instead of having the 'middle color' being in the middle of the rectange but to shift it say up by a quarter so that the 'middle color' separates the 'top' and 'bottom' color at three quarters of the way up?

Comment: You can fake it using twice `\shade[bottom color=cyan!60!black, top color=red, middle color = blue!20!white] (0,0) rectangle (4,5);` and changing the coordinates to produce two shades one above the other.

Comment: changing what coordinates?

Comment: The rectangle coordinates.

Comment: I was looking for a solution that could also be used for other shapes such as circles or more complicated shapes.

Comment: @KatyB You can use Sigur's solution combined with `clip` for other shapes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. In this answer I will try to cover the vertical shading: the concepts can be applied in the same way to the horizontal shading. Radial shading, instead is a bit different and the idea has been already implemented in [TikZ: radial shading of a ring](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82425/tikz-radial-shading-of-a-ring/82503#82503) to some extent.

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{vertical custom shading/.code={%
 \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@vcs@middle{#1}
 \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@vcs@bottom{\tikz@vcs@middle/2}
 \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@vcs@top{(100-\tikz@vcs@middle)/2+\tikz@vcs@middle}
\pgfdeclareverticalshading[tikz@axis@top,tikz@axis@middle,tikz@axis@bottom]{newaxis}{100bp}{%
  color(0bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
  color(\tikz@vcs@bottom bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
  color(\tikz@vcs@middle bp)=(tikz@axis@middle);
  color(\tikz@vcs@top bp)=(tikz@axis@top);
  color(100bp)=(tikz@axis@top)}
  \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/shading=newaxis}
  }
}
\makeatother  


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[top color=red,
      bottom color=blue, 
      middle color=white,
      vertical custom shading=60]
 (0,0) rectangle (4,2);

\draw[top color=blue,
      bottom color=red, 
      middle color=white,
      vertical custom shading=35]
 (5,0) rectangle (9,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Nice! So easy to understand the theory behind the codes. Math!!

Comment: @Sigur: Indeed, you always need some math for drawings. :)

Comment: @Claudio Fiandrino, how to execute this command within the `scope` with optional argument `canvas transform={rotate around={10:(0,0)}}`?