# Trying to understand the code and failing to manipulate it for new network

Tags: tikz-pgf, code

I have a code for 3 wires network. But I'm not able to manipulate it new figure.
This is because I'm not able to understand the code completely. This is my code

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\wireheight{2} % height of one segment
\newcommand\wirewidth{1}  % width of a segment
\newcommand\wiredist{0.5} % distance between wires
\pgfmathsetmacro\pairdist{2*(\wirewidth+\wiredist)} % distance between pairs of wires

% \wire[options]{name}{start}{height}{width}
\newcommand\wire[5][]%
{\draw[#1]
    (#3)            coordinate (#2-0)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-1)
    -- ++(#5,0)     coordinate (#2-2)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-3)
    -- ++(-#5,0)    coordinate (#2-4)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-5)
    -- ++(#5,0)     coordinate (#2-6)
    -- ++(0,0.5*#4) coordinate (#2-7);
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners,>=stealth, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt]
    \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
    {
        \wire[thick,red]{R-\i}{{(\i)*\pairdist-\wiredist},0}{\wireheight}{-\wirewidth}
        \wire[thick,blue]{B-\i}{\i*\pairdist,0}{\wireheight}{\wirewidth}
        \wire[thick,green]{G-\i}{{\i*\pairdist-0.5*\wiredist},0}{\wireheight}{0}
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I am trying to change the parameters to get this. At places 1 and 2 we have darker colors for red and green but not for black. At 3 we have light color for red and green (color black is constant) in the above figure.

[image]

Only even the working of the code is explained properly, I will be very grateful.

Comment: Do you want to have a gradient or sharp transitions between the lighter and darker regions?

Comment: @marmot Sharp transition, exactly at position 1 and 2. But it should mimic the above figure.

Comment: But then you already got an answer which does it, and I'd recommend to add a comment about a potentially missing feature there.

Comment: @marmot Spacings are different and also the segment at 1 is larger than segment at 2. Then network bulge out at 3, where green and red meet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fact is that you must redraw what is contained in the function, in the code that I have done, I have redrawn everything and redifined new nodes, not just a line, but a shape, which allows me to obtain a false variation in thickness, then I have added the scope structure, which allows me to obtain the mirror-like drawing `xscale=-1`, and move everything together towards a specific coordinate, then a second definition that allows me to draw a cell formed by the two wires and the middle line; so I can draw several, node IDs are also used, I also leave some commands to find any node.

Try changing the coordinates so that you can see how the modifiers affect, so you can be guided by the [visual tikz 7.6 links](http://tug.ctan.org/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf#subsection.7.6)

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{myred}{HTML}{8F3132}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{395D4E}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % New command to draw a single shape with named coordinates ans some controls like colors
    \def\Wire(#1)#2[#3](#4){% This draw one cell #1:position #2:color #3: Identifier #4: scale only 1 or -1
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},xscale=#4]% To modify the shape you must redefine the drawing within scope
        \draw[fill,#2] (0,0)%Starting point
            to ++(0,-1) % when use ++ you find a point relative to the starting point but shifted ++(xshift,yshift)
            to [in=90, out=-90]++(-2,-1) coordinate (a#3) %line direction from initial node in -90 degree direction and comes to the second in 90 direction, drawing a curved path. 
            to ++(0,-2) coordinate (b#3)
            to [in=90, out=-90]++(2,-1) coordinate (c#3)
            to ++(0,-0.5) coordinate (d#3)
            to [in=90, out=-90]++(-1,-1.5) coordinate (e#3)
            to ++(0,-0.1) coordinate (f#3)
            to [in=90, out=-90]++(1,-1.5) coordinate (g#3)
            to ++(0,-1) coordinate (h#3)
            to ++(-0.1,0)%go reverse shifted 0.1
            to ++(0,1)
            to [in=-90, out=90]++(-1+0.08,1.5)% +0.08 to get 0.02 of shifting in this point
            to ++(0,0.1)
            to [in=-90, out=90]++(1-0.08,1.5) %- 0.08 to compensate the value substracted and return to 0.1 shift value.
            to ++(0,0.5)
            to [in=-90, out=90]++(-2,1) % idem
            to ++(0,2)
            to [in=-90, out=90]++(2+0.08,1)
            to ++(0,1)
            to cycle;
            \draw[draw=none] (a#3) -- (b#3) node [midway](text1){};\draw(text1)++(0.4,0) node[#2]{\sf 3};
            \draw[draw=none] (c#3) -- (d#3) node [midway](text2){};\draw(text2)++(-0.4,0) node[#2]{\sf 2};
            \draw[draw=none] (g#3) -- (h#3) node [midway](text3){};\draw(text3)++(-0.4,0) node[#2]{\sf 1};

    \end{scope}
    }

    \def\cell(#1)[#2]{%#1:position, #2:ID
        \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
            \Wire(0,0){myred}[L#2](1)% All the cordinates are labeled as L(identifier) result in aL1,bL1 ... aL2,hL2...
            \draw[thick] (0.25,0) -- ++(0,-9.6); % the middle line
            \Wire(0.5,0){mygreen}[R#2](-1) %All the cordinates are labeled as R(identifier) result in aR1,bR1 ... aR2,hR2...
        \end{scope}
    }
    %Start drawing the thing...

    \cell(0,0)[1]
    \draw node at (0.25,0.5) {\sf Command; \verb+\cell(0,0)[1]+};   
    \cell(-5,0)[2]
    \draw node at (-4.75,0.5) {\sf Command; \verb+\cell(-5,0)[2]+};
    \cell(5,0)[3]
    \draw node at (5.25,0.5) {\sf Command; \verb+\cell(5,0)[3]+};
    \Wire(10,0){blue}[L4](1)
    \draw node (comment1) at (7.5,-10.5) {\sf Command; \verb+\Wire(10,0){blue}[L4](1)+};

    %Demostration nodes:
    \draw[-Stealth,shorten >= 5pt,] (comment1) -- (hL4);
    \draw[-Stealth,shorten >= 2pt,shorten <= 2pt] (fR2) -- (fL1) node [midway,align=center,anchor=south]{Node IDs \\ available};
    %Find nodes
    \draw node[anchor=east] at (bR1) {\sf Node \verb+bR1+} (bR1)[fill=red] circle (2pt);
    \draw node[anchor=east] at (aR2) {\sf Node \verb+aR2+} (aR2)[fill=red] circle (2pt);
    \draw node[anchor=west] at (aL2) {\sf Node \verb+aL2+} (aL2)[fill=red] circle (2pt);
    \draw node[anchor=east] at (eL3) {\sf Node \verb+eL3+} (eL3)[fill=red] circle (2pt);
    \draw node[anchor=east] at (fL4) {\sf Node \verb+fL4+} (fL4)[fill=red] circle (2pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### Update

In a crazy idea; why not to create a cropped area with the same figure and draw within it the shaders in the positions of the texts, doing that I get:

RESULT:
[image]

UPDATED MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{myred}{HTML}{8F3132}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{395D4E}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % New command to draw a single shape with named coordinates ans some controls like colors
    \def\Wire(#1)#2[#3](#4){% This draw one cell #1:position #2:color #3: Identifier #4: scale only 1 or -1
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},xscale=#4]% To modify the shape you must redefine the drawing within scope
        \draw[fill,#2] (0,0)%Starting point
            to ++(0,-1) % when use ++ you find a point relative to the starting point but shifted ++(xshift,yshift)
            to [in=90, out=-90]++(-2,-1) coordinate (a#3) %line direction from initial node in -90 degree direction and comes to the second in 90 direction, drawing a curved path. 
            to ++(0,-2) coordinate (b#3)
            to [in=90, out=-90]++(2,-1) coordinate (c#3)
            to ++(0,-0.5) coordinate (d#3)
            to [in=90, out=-90]++(-1,-1.5) coordinate (e#3)
            to ++(0,-0.1) coordinate (f#3)
            to [in=90, out=-90]++(1,-1.5) coordinate (g#3)
            to ++(0,-1) coordinate (h#3)
            to ++(-0.1,0)%go reverse shifted 0.1
            to ++(0,1)
            to [in=-90, out=90]++(-1+0.08,1.5)% +0.08 to get 0.02 of shifting in this point
            to ++(0,0.1)
            to [in=-90, out=90]++(1-0.08,1.5) %- 0.08 to compensate the value substracted and return to 0.1 shift value.
            to ++(0,0.5)
            to [in=-90, out=90]++(-2,1) % idem
            to ++(0,2)
            to [in=-90, out=90]++(2+0.08,1)
            to ++(0,1)
            to cycle;
            \draw[draw=none] (a#3) -- (b#3) node [midway](text1){};\draw(text1)++(0.4,0) node[#2]{\sf 3};
            \draw[draw=none] (c#3) -- (d#3) node [midway](text2){};\draw(text2)++(-0.4,0) node[#2]{\sf 2};
            \draw[draw=none] (g#3) -- (h#3) node [midway](text3){};\draw(text3)++(-0.4,0) node[#2]{\sf 1};
            \clip (0,0)%Starting point
            to ++(0,-1) % when use ++ you find a point relative to the starting point but shifted ++(xshift,yshift)
            to [in=90, out=-90]++(-2,-1)  %line direction from initial node in -90 degree direction and comes to the second in 90 direction, drawing a curved path. 
            to ++(0,-2) 
            to [in=90, out=-90]++(2,-1) 
            to ++(0,-0.5) 
            to [in=90, out=-90]++(-1,-1.5)
            to ++(0,-0.1)
            to [in=90, out=-90]++(1,-1.5)
            to ++(0,-1)
            to ++(-0.1,0)%go reverse shifted 0.1
            to ++(0,1)
            to [in=-90, out=90]++(-1+0.08,1.5)% +0.08 to get 0.02 of shifting in this point
            to ++(0,0.1)
            to [in=-90, out=90]++(1-0.08,1.5) %- 0.08 to compensate the value substracted and return to 0.1 shift value.
            to ++(0,0.5)
            to [in=-90, out=90]++(-2,1) % idem
            to ++(0,2)
            to [in=-90, out=90]++(2+0.08,1)
            to ++(0,1)
            to cycle;
            \fill[inner color=black,outer color=#2](text1) circle (1.5cm);
            \fill[inner color=black,outer color=#2](text2) circle (1.5cm);
            \fill[inner color=black,outer color=#2](text3) circle (1.5cm);

    \end{scope}
    }

    \def\cell(#1)[#2]{%#1:position, #2:ID
        \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
            \Wire(0,0){red}[L#2](1)% All the cordinates are labeled as L(identifier) result in aL1,bL1 ... aL2,hL2...
            \draw[thick] (0.25,0) -- ++(0,-9.6); % the middle line
            \Wire(0.5,0){green}[R#2](-1) %All the cordinates are labeled as R(identifier) result in aR1,bR1 ... aR2,hR2...
        \end{scope}
    }
    %Start drawing the thing...

    \cell(0,0)[1]
    \draw node at (0.25,0.5) {\sf Command; \verb+\cell(0,0)[1]+};   
    \cell(-5,0)[2]
    \draw node at (-4.75,0.5) {\sf Command; \verb+\cell(-5,0)[2]+};
    \cell(5,0)[3]
    \draw node at (5.25,0.5) {\sf Command; \verb+\cell(5,0)[3]+};
    \Wire(10,0){blue}[L4](1)
    \draw node (comment1) at (7.5,-10.5) {\sf Command; \verb+\Wire(10,0){blue}[L4](1)+};

    %Demostration nodes:
    \draw[-Stealth,shorten >= 5pt,] (comment1) -- (hL4);
    \draw[-Stealth,shorten >= 2pt,shorten <= 2pt] (fR2) -- (fL1) node [midway,align=center,anchor=south]{Node IDs \\ available};
    %Find nodes
    \draw node[anchor=east] at (bR1) {\sf Node \verb+bR1+} (bR1)[fill=red] circle (2pt);
    \draw node[anchor=east] at (aR2) {\sf Node \verb+aR2+} (aR2)[fill=red] circle (2pt);
    \draw node[anchor=west] at (aL2) {\sf Node \verb+aL2+} (aL2)[fill=red] circle (2pt);
    \draw node[anchor=east] at (eL3) {\sf Node \verb+eL3+} (eL3)[fill=red] circle (2pt);
    \draw node[anchor=east] at (fL4) {\sf Node \verb+fL4+} (fL4)[fill=red] circle (2pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

PSD: some spelling error corrected in line 84, first MWE; thanks to @manooooh.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use [Tikz: Shading a path without any filling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134297/151808) and
[Is it possible to define the position of top bottom and middle color in fill?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191742/151808), with no success.

Thus, I just re-draw some paths

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\wireheight{2} % height of one segment
\newcommand\wirewidth{1}  % width of a segment
\newcommand\wiredist{0.5} % distance between wires
\pgfmathsetmacro\pairdist{2*(\wirewidth+\wiredist)} % distance between pairs of wires

% \wire[options]{name}{start}{height}{width}
\NewDocumentCommand{\wire}{sO{}mmmmmO{left}}{%
\draw[#2,#3!50]
    (#5)            coordinate (#4-0)
    -- ++(0,#6)     coordinate (#4-1)
    -- ++(#7,0)     coordinate (#4-2)
    -- ++(0,#6)     coordinate (#4-3)
    -- ++(-#7,0)    coordinate (#4-4)
    -- ++(0,#6)     coordinate (#4-5)
    -- ++(#7,0)     coordinate (#4-6)
    -- ++(0,0.5*#6) coordinate (#4-7);
\IfBooleanF{#1}{\draw[#2,#3!80!black]($(#4-0)+(0,5pt)$) -- ($(#4-1)-(0,5pt)$) node [pos=.5, #8] {1} ($(#4-4)+(0,5pt)$) -- ($(#4-5)-(0,5pt)$) node [pos=.5, #8] {2};}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=5pt,>=stealth, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt]
    \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
    {
        \wire[thick]{red}{R-\i}{{(\i)*\pairdist-\wiredist},0}{\wireheight}{-\wirewidth}
        \wire[thick]{Green}{G-\i}{\i*\pairdist,0}{\wireheight}{\wirewidth}[right]
        \wire*[thick]{black}{B-\i}{{\i*\pairdist-0.5*\wiredist},0}{\wireheight}{0}
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Edit

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\wireheight{2} % height of one segment
\newcommand\wirewidth{1}  % width of a segment
\newcommand\wiredist{0.5} % distance between wires
\pgfmathsetmacro\pairdist{2.2*(\wirewidth+\wiredist)} % distance between pairs of wires

% \wire[options]{name}{start}{height}{width}
\NewDocumentCommand{\wire}{sO{}mmmmmO{left}}{%
\draw[#2,#3!50]
    (#5)            coordinate (#4-0)
    -- ++(0,#6)     coordinate (#4-1)
    -- ++(#7,0)     coordinate (#4-2)
    -- ++(0,#6)     coordinate (#4-3)
    -- ++(-.8*#7,0)    coordinate (#4-4)
    -- ++(0,.5*#6)     coordinate (#4-5)
    -- ++(.8*#7,0)     coordinate (#4-6)
    -- ++(0,#6) coordinate (#4-7)
    -- ++(-#7,0) coordinate (#4-8)
    -- ++(0,.5*#6) coordinate (#4-9);
\IfBooleanF{#1}{\draw[#2,#3!80!black]($(#4-0)+(0,5pt)$) -- ($(#4-1)-(0,5pt)$) node [pos=.5, #8] {1} ($(#4-4)+(0,5pt)$) -- ($(#4-5)-(0,5pt)$) node [pos=.5, #8] {2} ($(#4-6)+(0,5pt)$) -- ($(#4-7)-(0,5pt)$) node [pos=.5, #8] {3};}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=5pt,>=stealth, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt]
    \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
    {
        \wire[thick]{red}{R-\i}{{(\i)*\pairdist-\wiredist},0}{\wireheight}{-\wirewidth}
        \wire[thick]{Green}{G-\i}{\i*\pairdist,0}{\wireheight}{\wirewidth}[right]
        \wire*[thick]{black}{B-\i}{{\i*\pairdist-0.5*\wiredist},0}{\wireheight}{0}
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Edit 2

Very last attempt…

You have to play with the 3 defined wire lengths plus with the coordinates defined in the `\wire` command to fit your needs where you see `x×#7` or `y×#6`

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\wireheight{2} % height of one segment
\newcommand\wirewidth{1.2}  % width of a segment
\newcommand\wiredist{0.5} % distance between wires
\pgfmathsetmacro\pairdist{2.2*(\wirewidth+\wiredist)} % distance between pairs of wires

% \wire*[options]{color}{name}{start}{height}{width}[side for label]
\NewDocumentCommand{\wire}{sO{}mmmmmO{left}}{%
\draw[#2,#3!50]
    (#5)            coordinate (#4-0)
    -- ++(0,#6)     coordinate (#4-1)
    -- ++(.6*#7,0)     coordinate (#4-2)
    -- ++(0,#6)     coordinate (#4-3)
    -- ++(-.4*#7,0)    coordinate (#4-4)
    -- ++(0,.5*#6)     coordinate (#4-5)
    -- ++(.8*#7,0)     coordinate (#4-6)
    -- ++(0,#6) coordinate (#4-7)
    -- ++(-#7,0) coordinate (#4-8)
    -- ++(0,.5*#6) coordinate (#4-9);
\IfBooleanF{#1}{\draw[#2,#3!80!black]($(#4-0)+(0,5pt)$) -- ($(#4-1)-(0,5pt)$) node [pos=.5, #8] {1} ($(#4-4)+(0,5pt)$) -- ($(#4-5)-(0,5pt)$) node [pos=.5, #8] {2};
    \node at ($(#4-6)!.5!(#4-7)$) [#3!80!black, #8] {3};
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=5pt,>=stealth, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt]
    \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
    {
        \wire[thick]{red}{R-\i}{{(\i)*\pairdist-\wiredist},0}{\wireheight}{-\wirewidth}
        \wire[thick]{Green}{G-\i}{\i*\pairdist,0}{\wireheight}{\wirewidth}[right]
        \wire*[thick]{black}{B-\i}{{\i*\pairdist-0.5*\wiredist},0}{\wireheight}{0}
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's different from the figure I have.

Comment: That is to say? What is missing?

Comment: Spacings are not same at 1,2 and 3. Also length of the segment at point 1 is longer than 2. There is no 3rd part in your figure (where network bulge out at 3, where green and red meet).

Comment: I guess you'll be able to make segments marked 3 ligther…

Comment: Wonderful! But is there a way to bulge out at 3 and make green and red closer than before. Else, there is no way to differentiate between actual 3 and segment between 1 and 2. And 3 I don't want darker color but the usual, only at 1 and 2, I want darker. Many thanks