# Filled contour from axis symmetric data

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have temperature data which is axis symmetric.(See Figure 1; apologies for my bad drawing)[image: Figure 1] The number(1 to 10) denotes the point of measurement. 
Now, From this data, how do I get a filled contour like Figure 2 and 3 ? Is it possible in pgfplots?
[image: Figure 2]
[image: Figure 3]

The last two figures are for representation purpose only.

Comment: did you check the manual? a `surf` plots might be the closest what you can do with pgfplots

Comment: Just check this:

Comment: http://www.ceus-now.com/tikz-radial-shading-of-a-ring/

Comment: @Francesco --> http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82425/tikz-radial-shading-of-a-ring

Comment: Yes @percusse, that's the same. Is what you wanted @SaravanaK?

Comment: @Francesco  I'm not sure. I'm looking for a graph rather than a picture. My contour colour should range from red(hottest) to blue (coolest) with a colourbar! Thanks anyway. I'll try if I can do something with it.

Comment: You may want to take a look at section "Filled Contour Plots" in the `pgfplots` reference manual. Limited support for filled contours is available since the current stable version 1.13 (see its documentation for limitations). Make sure you browse the manual in a decent pdf viewer -- `shader=interp` still poses challenges for `pdf.js` and other open source pdf viewers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `contour filled` in order to visualize the data and `data cs=polar` if you need polar coordinates:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colorbar, colormap/Spectral,view={0}{90}]
    \addplot3[
        domain=0:360,
        domain y=0:360,
        data cs=polar,
        contour filled={number=15},
    ]
    (x,y,{sin(y)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The key `data cs=polar` ensures that `x` is the angle, `y` the radius, and the `z` value is chosen as oscillating function in the range `-1:1`. The provided `colormap` is a "diverging" scheme of `colorbrewer` which is quite suitable for the oscillating function here, but you can use any other `colormap` as well. You can use any kind of input data (including table data) as long as it forms a mesh (i.e. has inherent matrix structure).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colorbar, xmin=0, ymin=0,colormap/Spectral,view={0}{90}]
    \addplot3[
        domain=0:360,
        domain y=0:360,
        data cs=polar,
        contour filled={number=15},
    ]
    (x,y,{sin(y)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `contour filled` requires pgfplots 1.14 or newer. At the time of this writing, you may need an update first (august 2016).