# How to shift the current path up?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, circuitikz

I'm trying to adap the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430448/add-current-paths-in-circuitikz/430456#430456) to add current flowing path to my circuit. 
Unfortunately, the result is not same as in the reference above. I want to shift the current path up a bit.
 How can I do that?

[image]

Does every node has all anchors such as north, south, east, west, north east, etc?  
I saw [this](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/contrib/tex-contrib/beamer/pgf-1.01/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-tex4ht/en/pgfmanualse11.html) but couldn't make it works.

Also I would be much appreciated if you can help me change the arrow to something nicer. This `\arrow{>=stealth}` does not work as probably I don't understand how to use that.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage[american,siunitx,RPvoltages]{circuitikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} 
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\ctikzset{ inductors/scale=0.5, capacitors/scale=0.5, sources/scale=0.5, switches/scale=0.5 }

\draw  (0,0) coordinate (start)  node[ocirc]{} to [cute open switch]
++(1,0)  to [cute inductor, l^=$L$] ++(1,0) to [short]++(0.5,0) node[ocirc]{} coordinate (end);


 % adding current \begin{scope}[on background layer, very thick, decoration = {
        markings,
        mark = at position 0.2 with {\arrow{>}}} ]  \draw[line width = 2pt, red!40, postaction = {decorate}] (start.north)--(end.north);   \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All nodes has anchors such as north, south, east, west, north east, etc. A `coordinate` as you use here has no size, so all the anchors are at the same location. It is better to use arrows from `arrows.meta` than the old ones (Notice `Stealth` not `stealth`).

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone} 
\usepackage[american, siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta} 
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\ctikzset{inductors/scale=0.5, capacitors/scale=0.5, sources/scale=0.5, switches/scale=0.5}
\draw  (0,0) coordinate (start)  node[ocirc]{} to [cute open switch]
++(1,0)  to [cute inductor, l^=$L$] ++(1,0) to [short]++(0.5,0) node[ocirc]{} coordinate (end);
\begin{scope}[on background layer, decoration={
markings, mark=at position 0.2 with {\arrow{Stealth[scale=0.8]}}} ]  
\draw[ultra thick, red!40, postaction={decorate}] ([yshift=1pt]start) -- ([yshift=1pt]end);   
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A small circuit wit red arrow in background]

Or as in comments:

```
\draw[ultra thick, red!40, postaction={decorate}, transform canvas={yshift=1pt}] (start) -- (end);
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you! If the path is not straight lines,  do I have to specify the shift for every points? I'm thinking if I'll have to add `xshift` or `yshift` for every points. I still don't get how does that work for the reference one but not here. I think the reference one also nodes with no size?

Comment: You could use `\draw[ultra thick, red!40, postaction={decorate}, transform canvas={yshift=1pt}] (start) -- (end);` to move the whole path. This comes with its own limitations and dangers.

Comment: Yeah, that is shorter but I can only do that with straight line. Probably I could define `node` instead of `coordinate` so I can make it simple as in the link.

Comment: No you can do that with any path: `\draw[transform canvas={yshift=1pt}] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1);`

Comment: How about this? For the circuit I changed it to this `\draw  (0,0) coordinate (start)  node[ocirc]{} to [cute open switch]
++(1,0)  to [cute inductor, l^=$L$] ++(1,0) to [short]++(0.5,0) node[ocirc]{} coordinate (end) to [cute open switch] ++(0,-1)  node[ground]{} coordinate (ground);` and then `\draw[ultra thick, red!40, postaction={decorate}, transform canvas={yshift=3pt}] (start) --(end)-- (ground);` to draw but it does not work for the second section to ground. 
https://ibb.co/Ykd7Tp4

I don't expect this would work though. The second section I shuold shift x to the right instead.

Comment: more on transformations can be found here: https://tikz.dev/base-transformations. Be careful using the more advanced levels of transformation.

Comment: It does work, but your ground coordinate is not where you want it, you could name the node instead like this: `... node[ground] (ground) {};`. If you need further help, then please edit your question or ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask a new question as it does not seem to relate to this.