# includesvg, absurdly large image margin

Tags: pdftex, svg

I am trying to include an SVG image into my document which had always (kind of) seemed to work when using `\includesvg`. But now I have an image that I created from a postscript file, modified in Inkscape (saved as plain svg), which is not centered at all when included using:

```
\begin{figure}                                                                   
  \centering                                                                     
     \includesvg{resources/svg/an-image}                                                                                                
\end{figure}
```

When I run everything through `pdflatex`, the left border of the image is positioned in the center of the page, most of the right part is cut off and if I add a caption it is placed way below the images lower border. It looks as if the image had a very large empty margin (which it definitely does not have in the SVG file).

Unfortunately the image itself is confidential so I cannot share it here.
What might be the cause of this? Might there be a workaround using another command than `\includesvg` (that one has caused me unnecessary trouble before)?

Comment: Can you copy the .svg file, replace everything confidential with one large rectangle and if this also produces the error, share the svg file for us to test?

Comment: if you work with Inkscape, yo just save a copy in pdf format and import it using graphicx package like in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424382/154390)

Comment: After some inspection I believe the problem probably lies with inkscape, the apparent image size after including the image with `\includesvg` approximately matches the pagesize in Inkscape before resizing to the actual content's dimensions. I will just do as suggested and use another file format for now.

Comment: I believe there is little advantage in exporting a modified postscript as `.svg` as opposed to, say, PDF if you only want to include it in a `.tex` document.

Answer (score 1):

You may have invisible objects that extend outside of the SVG's viewBox (inksacpe's page). Have a look at the `inkscapearea` option. Possible values are

- `drawing`/`nocrop` (default) : adjust SVG viewbox to fit all elements.
- `page`/`nocrop` : respect SVG viewBox.