# How to define "ball" style for mindmap node?

Tags: mindmaps

I need to change the style of the concepts in the following mindmap to 3D "ball" style, similar to [How to shade mindmap concepts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58249/how-to-shade-mindmap-concepts)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,decorations}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand\etoc{\textcolor{joli}{\ttfamily\bfseries etoc}\xspace}
\DeclareRobustCommand\csa[1]{{\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font45 \char`\\ #1}}
\makeatletter
\newcount\tikzcountgrandchild
\def\tikz@grow@concentric{%
\pgftransformreset%
\pgftransformrotate{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle})* 
(\tikzcountgrandchild)}%
\ifnum\tikztreelevel=1
\pgftransformrotate{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle})* 
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/noc}-1)/2}%
\fi
\pgftransformxshift{\the\tikzleveldistance}%
\ifnum\tikztreelevel=2
\global\advance\tikzcountgrandchild by1
\fi
}
\tikzset{
noc/.initial=0,
branch color/.style={
    concept color=#1!white,
    every child/.append style={concept color=#1!white!30!white}
}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[text width=3cm,align=flush center,
                mindmap,growth function=\tikz@grow@concentric,
                sibling angle=360/22,nodes={concept},concept 
 color=orange!60,
                level 1/.style={level distance=8cm},
                level 2/.style={level distance=16cm}
               ]
 \node{\Large\textbf{Xbox}}
 child[noc=6,branch color=teal!60]{node{Group 1}
    child{node{Nancy}}
    child{node{Paul \& Peach}}
    child{node{Stacy \& Sala}}
    child{node{Ali \& Sara}}
    child{node{Rose}}
    child{node{Lena}}
}
child[noc=5,branch color=green!50]{node{Group 2 }
    child{node{Mitra1}}
    child{node{Mitra2}}
    child{node{Mitra3}}
    child{node{Mitra4}}
    child{node{Mitra5}}
}
child[noc=3,branch color=yellow!80]{node{Group 3}
    child{node{Nolan \& Mike}}
    child{node{Steve \& Synthia}}
    child{node{Shannon \& Bill}}
}
child[noc=5,branch color=green!50]{node{Group 4}
    child{node{Mitra1}}
    child{node{Mitra2}}
    child{node{Mitra3}}
    child{node{Mitra4}}
    child{node{Mitra5}}
}
child[noc=3,branch color=yellow!80]{node{Group 5}
    child{node{Peggy}}
    child{node{Caleb \& Unknown}}
    child{node{Susan}}
}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `ball color=#1!white!30!white` or whatever colour you want instead of `concept color=#1!white!30!white`. (Does this work? What does the first `white` do? Why not just `#1!30!white`?

Comment: Not changing shape by using ball color. Yes, I think #1!30!white is the right code. - @cfr

Comment: `ball color`  doesn't change the shape, although it only really makes sense for things which are roughly circular generally. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I need to change the shape of circles to balls. How can I code that? @cfr

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Isn't a ball in 2D a circle?