# GO board drawing with flexible annotations

Tags: diagrams, annotations, puzzle

As Tikz beginner, I'd learn skills for GO board drawing to do the following conveniently:

1. add stones in arbitrary board positions (BOTH for grid points and unit squares) with text tag or other indicators of shape, color, etc.;
2. label X,Y axis systematically and selectively;
3. indicate arbitrary rectangles on the board by color or bounds;
4. add comments outside of the board such that they have multiple line arrows pointing to arbitrary positions of the board, for example, all opposite boundary position pairs have a common property, several inner positions have a common property, etc.

Comment: See the answers to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1947/is-there-a-way-to-tune-ball-shading-in-tikz

Comment: Perhaps not as this community commonly understood. But we can view GO board as a special case of grid. That is why I thought any thing relevant to grid may apply to GO board.  (I tried to add  certain tags but failed)

Comment: Thanks for the example. But I still need more help with items 2,3,4. For X,Y axis labeling, suppose X is labelled from 1 to 19, and Y from A to S. How to make a systematical labeling?

Comment: I've removed `grid-typesetting` as it is not relevant at all. Please read the tag wiki before adding tags if you aren't sure whether they're appropriate. I've added `puzzle` which is probably a better fit. There are packages for typesetting games on CTAN. Have you looked at those? What have you tried? `logicpuzzle` does grids. There are packages for chess and, I'm pretty sure, go. What have you tried?

Comment: https://ctan.org/topic/games There are at least 3 dedicated go support packages of some kind in that list and some of the others may also offer support, of course.

Comment: If the link helped with 1, then post the code you've got working and ask a specific question. The site works best when you ask for help with the particular step you're stuck on and don't just post a list of desiderata asking about various different things. Just because it is one project, doesn't mean you haven't asked four questions :-).

Answer (score 1):

The [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) package [metago](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/metago?lang=en) appears to work out of the box:

[image]

Perhaps this does what you want?  Here is the example from the documentation, wrapped up in `luamplib`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
However, a service-oriented paradigm is further compounded when taking into account
the evolution of specifications over a given time period.  
\[
\begin{mplibcode}
input metago
beginfig(1);
set_board_size 6;
init_board;
put_b(C4);
put_w(D4);
put_b(D3);
put_w(C3);
put_b(E4);
put_w(B4);
put_b(D5);
display_board;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\]
Is this what you need?

\end{document}
```

You need to compile my example using `lualatex`, or adapt it for `gmp` + `pdflatex`.

If your objective is to learn TikZ, then metago would at least provide you a benchmark for your efforts.